# No sound from MacBook Air (Mid 2013) from headphones or speakers and even if I install Windows 10 on it

Tags: macbook, sound-card

I’m using MacBook Air (Mid 2013) model.

I just realized sound is not coming out of this MacBook. No sound from internal speaker an no sound from headphones.

I tried resetting PRAM, merged all partitions and formatted and reinstalled Mac OS X. It still does not work.

I installed Windows 10 on MacBook. And it does not work there either.

I don’t see any output sound device from MacOS “audio settings.”

What else can I try? If it is mainboard error, what can I do with it instead of just getting changed by Apple?

Comment: I had the exact same issue with Windows 10 bootcamp on my Macbook Air 2013 Mid. Go to Device Manager, rollback the sound driver. Restart. Then update the sound driver again. Worked for me, see how it goes

Comment: @Insane I just tried it but it does not work. Actually it is not just windows problem. I think OS does not matter. Both OS can not detect sound device(no internal speaker, no headphone) Thank you for your suggestion anyways.

Comment: Just to confirm, no [ding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9qOJqNjalE), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like there is a hardware issue with either your speaker, speaker connector or Logic Board - If you are not getting any sound, especially after a PRAM/NVRAM reset, and not seeing any sound devices, then your speaker is either not connected to the board, or damaged.

if your laptop is still covered under warranty, I suggest taking it to the Apple Store to have it looked at and tested. However, if your laptop is not covered anymore, and you are interested in delving a bit deeper into your laptop, you can following the following guide to take your laptop apart to ensure that your Right/Left speaker cables are connected properly, and to ensure your speakers or cables are not physically damaged:

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2013+Logic+Board+Replacement/15388

In my expert opinion, the chance of both left and right speaker cables not being connected is rather slim. This sounds like the Logic Board may be faulty and no longer transmitting audio properly. If you are covered under warranty, they will replace it for you no questions. If it is no longer covered, this can be a rather expensive repair.

Comment: Thank you for detaild answer. Like you said I don't think it's speaker problem because headphones are not working too. Unfortunately my warranty is over. Wow Logic Board is expensive!

Comment: @SeniorLee ya - Logic Board replacements are not cheap (they are effectively "the laptop." - You could try taking it to the Apple Store and have them diagnose it anyway. They are able to do Out-Of-Warranty repairs for an issue like this. They are usually about $300-$400 or so.

Comment: I solved this by replacing the IO board. It was not the software problem. It was hardware problem. Like Mike suggest, bought IO board and followed steps from ifixit and succeed to fixing it by myself. Thank you.